# Productivity issues when debugging in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, debugging, webstorm

In WebStorm, when I write some javascript such as:

```
var obj= {name:'Fred'}
console.log(obj)
```

...and then start the debugger, the debugger console shows:

```
Object
```

To actual look at the content, I have to hover over, wait for a tooltip to appear, and then click it, resulting in another window opening up revealing the contents of Object.

This is a productivity killer. Is there a setting available that allows me to see the data immediately?

Answer (score 0):

Please feel free to vote for [WEB-14856](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14856).
You can use 'quick evaluate' (`alt+click`) instead of hovering over.

Answer (score -1):

How about logging JSON.stringify(obj) so that it makes the object into a JSON string?